# Cannot read property of 'touched' undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, undefined, formik

I'm using Formik to create forms in my React app, and using custom components as my Inputs, like so:

```
  <Field
    ...
    component={Input}
  />
```

However, when I use `Input` outside of a Formik form, I get the following error: `Cannot read property of 'touched' undefined`

My Input looks like this:

```
const Input = React.forwardRef(
  (
    { value, onChange, onKeyPress, placeholder, type, label, form: {touched, errors}, field, ...props },
    ref
  ) => (
      <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
        {label && (
          <label style={{ fontWeight: 700, marginBottom: `${scale.s2}rem` }}>
            {label}
          </label>
        )}
        <input
          ref={ref}
          style={{
            borderRadius: `${scale.s1}rem`,
            border: `1px solid ${color.lightGrey}`,
            padding: `${scale.s3}rem`,
            marginBottom: `${scale.s3}rem`
          }}
          value={value}
          onChange={onChange}
          onKeyPress={onKeyPress}
          placeholder={placeholder ? placeholder : "Type something..."}
          type={type ? type : "text"}
          {...field}
          {...props}
        />
        {touched[field.name] &&
          errors[field.name] && <div className="error">{errors[field.name]}</div>}
      </div>
    )
)
```

I'm not sure why `touched` should be undefined, seems it's conditionally rendered?

[Link to Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lp58rkkmkm)

Desired outcome: The `Input` should work both inside and outside of Formik.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: It would probably mean that there is no property `form` in the passed object.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work you have at least modify this line

```
<Input ref={"this.ref"} value={0} form={{}} />
```

And also this line

```
{touched && touched[field.name] && errors[field.name] && (
```

You're not passing `form` and `touched` as props to `Input` component, so they are `undefined`. You also not passing other props of `Input` component. So it can be good idea to review code.